# Problem when I changed Fish to default shell

Tags: command-line, bash, default, fish

So I tried to make Fish my default shell with the command:

```
sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/fish 'myUsername'
```

Now I get this every time that I launch my terminal:

```
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type help for instructions on how to use fish
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
```

I've tried using:   `sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/bash 'myUsername'`

But then I get:

```
chsh: PAM: Authentication failure
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
```

Is there a way to fix what I messed up? I'd like to revert back to bash.
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Ye probably just an owner issue since you used sudo during the change the system might have created this "fishd.Dlorah" file as root:root, Just let `sudo chown user:usergroup -R /home/user` run and that might already help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
Still getting that PAM authentication failure after I tried that out though. It hung for quite a bit before it gave me back the terminal.

Comment: Can you show us the permissions of the file and what is actually in there?

Comment: Honestly, I'm very new to all of this. How would I go about that?

Comment: I found the answer. I'm not sure about linking policies, but here it is http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1702833  Thanks for the help Ziazis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this link and it fixed my problem along with what Ziazis originally suggested

Ziazis' suggestion:

```
sudo chown user:usergroup -R /home/user
```

Once that was implemented, I stopped getting the

```
Unable to open universal variable file '/home/username/.config/fish/fishd.Dlorah': Permission denied
```

error, but the PAM authentication error still came up. Some more googlin' and I found this link: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1702833

Comment: As long it works again everythings fine :)